# Is there an analytic formula for the kurtosis of a (student t) mixture distribution?

Tags: mixture-distribution, kurtosis

The mixture distribution should be composed of noncentral scaled student t components.

The mean of the mixture distribution can be calculated easily just by weighting the component means according to the mixing law. I also could derieve a tractable analytic formula for the mixture variance by means of the "law of total variance" in a straightforward way.

But for the kurtosis I found no low-level "shortcuts" to get a general analytic formula in this case.

Does anyone have seen such a formula in a book? Any suggestions for a straightforward derivation of such a formula would also be very helping!

Thanks a lot in advance!! Jo

Comment: It might depend on what you have in mind by "general analytic formula." At a minimum we should expect that any formula would depend essentially on the mixture weights and will therefore not reduce nicely to a closed form whose length remains independent of the number of weights. Because (raw) moments of mixtures are just weighted linear combinations of the moments of the components and kurtosis depends on the first through fourth raw moments, it is clear a formula exists for the kurtosis of the mixture--and, I hope, equally clear how to obtain it, even though it's a bit messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the law of total expectation to $E(Y^k)$, for $k=4,3,2,1$ and then obtain* a formula for $E[(Y-\mu_Y)^4]$. To get the kurtosis of course you still have to divide by $\sigma_Y^4$

* the conversion from raw to central moments at that point is straightforward, but to save you some labour, this can just be [looked up](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralMoment.html)

[If you desire it, you could derive a law of total fourth moments. However, I don't expect it will be especially enlightening, but in fact rather unwieldy.]

So, basically, take the formula you already have for $E(Y)$ in terms of the components, and put $k^\text{th}$ powers everywhere (since the formula should work just as well for the random variable $Y^* = Y^k$ as it does for the random variable $Y$). You now have a formula for the raw moments.

You then use $\mu_4 = \mu'_4 - 4 \mu \mu'_3 + 6 \mu^2 \mu'_2 - 3 \mu^4\,$ to obtain the 4th central moment, which you divide by the square of the variance you already have.

In practice I wouldn't actually derive a direct formula, but simply compute the raw moments, and then compute the central moments as needed. (In some circumstances numerical issues with the potential for cancellation in the above formula may need to be considered.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I just noticed that in order to get the noncentral moments of order 3 and 4 via the law of total expectation (1 is trivial and 2 can be backed out because I already have got the 2nd central moment) I need to get the noncentral moments of order 3 and 4 for the noncentral scaled student t components. I have found an article w.r.t. the noncentral t (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) where the noncentral moments are given. But I have found no article that also considers the scale. Any ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: If you're talking about a particular form of noncentral $t$ aside from one you have linked to you'd better define it or link to it, so we're looking at the same thing.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm alredy searching for the details of the implementation that is used in my particular application. It is the one that is used in the "gamlss.dist"-package (TF2) and in the "rugarch-package" (std) for R. I'll be back with more information soon. So far I only know that its parameters are the mean, the standard deviation and the degrees of freedom.

Comment: After some calculation it all boils down to getting the third and fourth raw moment of the classical non-standardized t distribution. It`s the one parametrized in terms of sigma (which is not the SD here) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Non-standardized_Student.27s_t-distribution . I tried to calculate the moments by hand. Seems like my math skills have suffered a bit lately. One needs integration by parts and nested product- and chain rules. I might start a new thread unless you know a shortcut?

Comment: Yes, there's certainly a shortcut because it's just an ordinary scale parameter, so $E[X^k]= E[\sigma^k\,(X/\sigma)^k]=\sigma^k E[(X/\sigma)^k]$. So just multiply the $k$-th raw moments for the standardized distribution by $\sigma^k$.

Comment: Unfortunately the random variable $X$ is not only scaled, but also shifted.

Comment: If you expand the shifted variable out, you can get back to raw moments.